# Find commit where a file was added across all branches

Tags: git

I am using git filter-branch to locate blobs back in history in my repository across all branches using:

https://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/

An example of the output from that script can be seen below:

```
15547,5149,22ff59d8d472e4d23e51bb083517282c23f016a3 code/thirdparty/Web.dll
14224,2055,1db8de4c4e237c171712caeeff8affa32925c3a8 code/Dictionaries/ge-GE.tdf
```

The above SHAs are for the objects/blobs themselves and does not reference a specific commit.

Notice in the recent history of the repository those files have been deleted from this repository (they are still in the history though).

Is there anyway to find the exact commit back in time that introduced those files above (notice I have a lot of branches and no way of knowing on which branch they were introduced)?

I have tried:

```
git log --all -- code/Dictionaries/ge-GE.tdf
```

but it finds nothing. Will it only search on local branches or will it also include the remote tracking branches?

Comment: `--all` will search all refs. That means all local branches, remote branches, and tags. Basically the content of `.git/refs/`. Are you *sure* you have the filename right? Is it in a subdirectory? If your goal is to remove large files from your repository, look at the [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) instead.

Comment: Also, I get a different output format from the script you reference.  `17    15    962daa446a682bf59321925009da8261bc0675b6  img/radical_onion.png`

Comment: Sorry I used the output from BFG (deleted files). I have now updated my original post to reflect the correct output from git filter branch but same result, no files found. Yes I know about BFG have used it before. Right now I am just trying to understand if its possible to find commits introducing a specific blob.

Comment: If you ran the `git-filter-branch` code from the blog to remove those files then they are not deleted, *they never existed*. They are removed from history. Obliterated. As far as Git is concerned *those files never happened*. Fortunately Git takes a while to garbage collect. You might be able to recover them using [`git-reflog`](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html) to find the old `HEAD` before you ran `git-filter-branch`.

Comment: The script from the blog just list those blops it does not modify them, you need to run e.g bfg afterwards to do the actual removal. So they are in the history somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `git log -- <filename>` and some switches.

- `--all` will visit all commits in all branches.
- `--topo-order` will do it in topographical order (ie. according to their relationship, not their date), guaranteeing that the last commit containing the file will be the one which added it.
- `--reverse` will reverse the order so the commit which added the file is first.

Put it all together: `git log --all --topo-order --reverse -- <filename>`.  The first commit will be the one which added it.

You can then use various formatting options like `--pretty=oneline` and pipe it to `head -1` to get just the one commit.

*NOTE* that you can't use `--limit` because that happens before ordering options like `--topo-order` and `--reverse`.

Comment: See my updated post, the above files are not found using the approach you describe.